# Google Maps- list of markers depends of zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of markers in my gmaps generated by:

```
document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML +=
            '<li class="list-sidebar '+ type +'"><a href="javascript:myclick(' +
            i + ')"  >' + name + '</a></li>';
```

I would like to make a list of markers like this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/listing-markers/

If You zoom in or zoom out, markers are visible on map and list or not. I know, it's **inBounds** but don't know how touse it for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well looking at the javascript in that page, the important lines are:

```
bounds = map.getBounds();

if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
    ...
}
```

`inBounds` is just the array they're using to output the list of those markers' titles.